# Sorting list of dictionaries using the values from another list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I got a list of dictionaries and want that to be sorted by a value from another dictionary.

This

```
[{'fld':'a1', 'sortkey':'k2'}, {'fld':'b1', 'sortkey':'k3'}, {'fld':'c1', 'sortkey':'k1'},{'fld':'d1', 'sortkey':'k3'}]
```

should use the following

```
[{'sortkey':'k1', 'value':9}, {'sortkey':'k2', 'value':10}, {'sortkey':'k3', 'value':7}]
```

and get to the following result

```
[ {'fld':'b1', 'sortkey':'k3'}, {'fld':'d1','sortkey':'k3'}, {'fld':'c1', 'sortkey':'k1'},{'fld':'a1', 'sortkey':'k2'} ]
```

Comment: Sorry, could you be more explicit how the first list is sorted by using the second list? Is it `list[i]['sortkey']` matching up to a dict in the second list that happens to have the *same* `sortkey` value, then sorting by the `value` value from that second dictionary?

Comment: @Fenikso - Earlier, I was trying to add the sort value to the first list, sort on the sort value and then remove sort value from the list.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters - Yes, your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to transform the second list into something you can actually *use* with any decent performance:

```
sort_map = {d['sortkey']: d['value'] for d in secondlist}

sorted(firstlist, key=lambda d: sort_map[d['sortkey']])
```

This presumes that for each `sortkey` value in `firstlist` there is a matching `sortkey` in the second.

This gives:

```
>>> firstlist = [{'fld':'a1', 'sortkey':'k2'}, {'fld':'b1', 'sortkey':'k3'}, {'fld':'c1', 'sortkey':'k1'},{'fld':'d1', 'sortkey':'k3'}]
>>> secondlist = [{'sortkey':'k1', 'value':9}, {'sortkey':'k2', 'value':10}, {'sortkey':'k3', 'value':7}]
>>> sort_map = {d['sortkey']: d['value'] for d in secondlist}
>>> sorted(firstlist, key=lambda d: sort_map[d['sortkey']])
[{'fld': 'b1', 'sortkey': 'k3'}, {'fld': 'd1', 'sortkey': 'k3'}, {'fld': 'c1', 'sortkey': 'k1'}, {'fld': 'a1', 'sortkey': 'k2'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Giving some names to your current lists:

```
data = [{'fld':'a1', 'sortkey':'k2'}, {'fld':'b1', 'sortkey':'k3'}, {'fld':'c1', 'sortkey':'k1'},{'fld':'d1', 'sortkey':'k3'}]
sorts = [{'sortkey':'k1', 'value':9}, {'sortkey':'k2', 'value':10}, {'sortkey':'k3', 'value':7}]
```

First I would convert `sorts` to the following:

```
{'k1': 9, 'k2': 10, 'k3': 7}
```

You can do this with the following code:

```
sorts_dict = {d['sortkey']: d['value'] for d in sorts}
```

Then you can get your final list using this:

```
result = sorted(data, key=lambda d: sorts_dict.get(d['sortkey']))
```