# python: How do I sort a list of dictionaries by the order of the values in the other list?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

The list of dictionaries must be reordered in the order of the values contained in the other list, as shown below.(In this case ["site"].)

The other list contains the values of the dictionary.

In the case of just dictionaries, it is easy to reorder them using comprehensions, etc., but
I could not think of a way to reorder the dictionary lists.

How is it possible to reorder them in this way?

```py
l = ["c", "b", "a"]
d = [
    {"id": 1, "site": "a"}, 
    {"id": 2, "site": "c"}, 
    {"id": 3, "site": "b"}
]

↓

[
    {"id": 2, "site": "c"}, 
    {"id": 3, "site": "b"}
    {"id": 1, "site": "a"}, 
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: @alexpdev -- Although related there are two differences: 1) OP is sorting a list rather than a dictionary, and 2) the sort order is based upon another list.

Comment: @DarrylG  This is the page I meant to comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880780/sorting-list-of-dictionaries-using-the-values-from-another-list-of-dictionaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 d.sort(key=lambda item: l.index(item['site']))
```

should do the trick.

If both lists are *really* big, a temporary map could be more efficient:

```
m = {item['site']: item for item in d}
d = [m[site] for site in l]
```